# GitHub PR task list

Tags: github, pull-request

in ButBucket there is very nice option regarding the PRs.
When I open a PR, a reviewer can comment something, I click on that comment and "create task". After doing this with many comments, I have a visible personal tasklist which I have to do before I merge.

See this photo, upper right: 3 open tasks (for his PR)
[image]

I don't see anything like this in GitHub, the only similar option seems that the reviewer (not me) can "request change", which is kinda strange, I want me to create that task list, not the reviewer.

So how can I do something similar in GitHub, so I don't longer have to search through all of the comments on a pull request to find follow-up items? thx